# Calling DLL using C#

Tags: c#, pointers, dll, struct, call

```
typedef struct
{
    // The contents of this struct are platform-dependent and subject to
    // change. You should not manipulate the contents of this struct directly.

    /*New stuff*/
//  HWND            m_hWnd;
//  HDEVNOTIFY      m_hDevNotify;

} fdGlove;


FGLOVEAPI fdGlove *fdOpen(char *pPort, bool bOnlyAllowSingleConnection = false);    
FGLOVEAPI int   fdClose(fdGlove *pFG);
FGLOVEAPI int   fdGetGloveHand(fdGlove *pFG);
FGLOVEAPI int   fdGetGloveType(fdGlove *pFG);
```

I have a DLL file called fglove.dll and I need using C# to call it.
I have written code like this:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class fdGlove
    { 

    }
    [DllImport("fglove.dll")]
    public static extern fdGlove fdOpen(string pPort, bool bOnlyAllowSingleConnection);
```

but when I debug the program it is has an error (Unable to find an entry point named 'fdOpen' in DLL 'fglove.dll'.)

Can someone point out what I have done wrong?

Comment: BTW, the language is named "C#", not "c sharp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the name of the exported symbol in Dependency Walker.  More than likely it will be _fdImport or something similar and you will need to update your DLLImportAttribute to match the exported name.

Answer (score 3):

fdOpen is using a default parameter - which can only mean you are trying to export a C++ function out of a DLL.  The result is that "fdOpen" is getting "name mangled" in the export table as something that looks like "fdOpen@YAXPB_W0I@Z".

You're better off exporting this function as C.  Declare and define fdOpen as follows:

```
extern "C" fdGlove* __stdcall fdOpen(char* pPort, bool bOnlyAllowSingleConnection);
```

Other possible issues:

1. The DLL isn't in the same directory as the EXE trying to load it.
2. You forgot to export the function from the DLL.  You need to use a .DEF file or the __declspec(dllexport) attribute on the function definition.  Use "dumpbin /exports fglove.dll" to figure out if this is the case.
3. Confusion between stdcall and cdecl compile options.  I get it confused, so try replacing "_*stdcall" with "*_cdecl" above.  Or try it without either attribute.

Comment: thanks you is helpful. After use dumpbin check it, the name appear something like "fdOpen@YAXPB_W0I@Z". 

but my c sharp coding is still error.
    [DllImport("fglove.dll",EntryPoint="?fdOpen@YAXPB_W0I@Z")]
    public static extern fdGlove fdOpen(string pPort, bool           bOnlyAllowSingleConnection);

how to import the pointer function in c sharp?

Comment: That whole "@YAXPB_W01@Z" sequence I just made up as an example of name c++ mangling.  You could try to use the function as exported out of the DLL.  If you can recompile fglove.dll to use the declaration provided above, that will likely help.  Otherwise, write a pure C wrapper DLL (and library) to translate the call between C to C++.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler of fglove is most likely doing so type of name mangling.

Use `DUMPBIN fglove.dll` to get the real names.

Then use `[DllImport("fglove.dll", EntryPoint='...')]` where ... is the real name.